# MySQL - Iterate Through Table

Tags: mysql, loops

I'm trying to figure out how I can iterate through a table to get a count of how many days an id is not in an Active status.

Say I have the following table:

| id | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Active | 1/15/21 |
| 1 | Inactive | 1/13/21 |
| 1 | Active | 1/12/21 |
| 1 | Inactive | 1/9/21 |
| 1 | Active | 1/7/21 |
| 2 | Active | 1/5/21 |
| 2 | Inactive | 1/4/21 |
| 2 | Inactive | 1/2/21 |
| 2 | Active | 1/1/21 |

The desired output for this example should be:

| id | Days Inactive |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |

I would like to do a DATEDIFF() when the status changes from Active to Inactive.

I can't just do a SELECT for Status <> Active and do a DATEDIFF() on the MAX and MIN dates in the range because it could go ACTIVE in between that range which would make the count different as seen in the example table.

I think I need a LOOP and/or CURSOR with a variable that gets added to as the count grows for each id, I'm just not sure exactly how to execute that.

Any suggestions or ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,count(*) as days_inactive FROM table
WHERE status like 'inactive' 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: That will count the number of times the id was inactive, not the number of days it was inactive.  Also, using a 'like' without a wildcard is not efficient, rather use '='

Comment: Welcome to the site. Rather post your suggested answer as a comment if you are unsure it will work.

Comment: Might've misunderstood, but won't the number of times the id was inactive, be the same as number of days it was inactive? Also thanks for pointing it out, will keep it in mind

Comment: It might go from Active to Inactive only once, but stay that way for 100 days, the answer then should be 100, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using variables. Just calculate the number of days from the previous date if and only if the id is the same and the current row is an active status, as follows.

```
select @id :=0, @lastDate := null;
select id, sum(DaysInactive) as DaysInactive
from (
     select id, (case when id = @id and status='Active' then datediff(tranDate, @lastDate) else 0 end) as DaysInactive
     , @id := id, @lastDate := tranDate
     from tablename
     order by id, TranDate
) as calc group by id
```

You can run the inner select separately to confirm that your calculations are correct. It should also work if your table has consecutive 'Inactive' or 'Active' statuses.
Adjust the above for your table and column names.